# How do I trim values or text that are selected in a ComboBox on an Access Form

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I have a ComboBox on an Access 2007 form.
I created a table that holds text values that feeds into the ComboBox.

The text is too long so I would like the text to become trimmed to the last 5 characters
when any value is selected.

**Example: In the ComboBox is: My Favorite Color is Green - 10001**

But if the user select Green, I only want to insert the code **10001** in the query using trim.

How do I trimmed the values/text that are selected so that only the code is passed on to the rest of the query?

```
PARAMETERS [Forms].[ExampleForm]![cboColor] Text ( 255 );

SELECT FavColor
FROM COLOR
WHERE FavColor IS NOT NULL
HAVING (MAX(FavColorCode)=Forms.ExampleForm!Right(Trim([cboColor]),5))
```

I am getting an error message of ***Undefined Function***.

Thanks everyone!

Guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a tip, may be:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms].[ExampleForm]![cboColor] Text ( 255 );

SELECT FavColor
FROM COLOR
WHERE FavColor IS NOT NULL
AND (MAX(FavColorCode)=Right(Trim([Forms].[ExampleForm]![cboColor]),5))
```

Your SQL Statement was incorrect, try this now

Answer (score 1):

It looks like @Luka showed you how to use those functions correctly with the value from `cboColor`.  However, after fixing that part of your query, I suspect the db engine will throw a different error:

*You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'FavColorCode' as part of an aggregate function.*

I think you need to either do something else instead of the `HAVING` clause, or add a `GROUP BY` clause and an aggregate expression to your `SELECT` fields list.  However I don't know how to fix the query because I don't understand what it's supposed to do.